# [eclipse plugin]saving and loading information of a wizard on an XML file

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I work on an eclipse plugin and I've created wizards with SWT / JFace.
In these wizards I need to record some information that has been specified by the users for future use. I saw an example that speaks about this part, I tried to do the same thing but I'm lost !

Behold the link

http://java-gui.info/Wiley-Professional.Java.Interfaces.with.SWT.JFace/12093/BBL0095.html

Is there anyone who can help me on this . What are the main steps that I must follow

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The link is right. Before exiting the wizard, save the data in dialog settings (got using getDialogSettings()) and on next launch restore getDialogSettings().get

May be you want to be more specific in the problem being faced.